# getting exit status 1 when I run the command nvm use 12.18.0

Tags: node.js, cmd, nvm

I have installed nvm on my windows machine and with nvm, I installed 2 node versions but it's not letting me change the version.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.64]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>nvm use 12.18.0
exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Sarmad' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


C:\Windows\system32>nvm version
1.1.7

C:\Windows\system32>nvm ls

  * 15.8.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    12.18.0

C:\Windows\system32>nvm use 12.18.0
exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Ali' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Please use the developers GitHub pages to check for these issues, before resorting to asking questions on a general programming site. What you have reported is a [known issue](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/405), because the software you are using has not been written to work properly on the target Operating System.

Comment: Okay! Thanks @Compo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ali you are getting this error because you are installing nvm in the default location. And that is your user's directory. Nvm for windows is an attempt to port from the linux and currently does not support spaces in the path.

I spent several hours trying to figure this out and none of these solutions work for me. If you install nvm in `c:\tools\` directory, (you might already have one if not just create it) should solve the problem.

**UPDATE Jan - 2023**
The writer of NVM for Windows has decided to deprecate it and there will be something coming up to replace it. See the announcement:

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki/Runtime

From the link:

> I intend to deprecate NVM for Windows after Runtime is released. There
> are two things slowing work on Runtime. First, client engagements. I
> am wrapping up the most time-consuming project this quarter and will
> have much more time in early spring 2023. The other thing slowing down
> Runtime development is this project. So, I'm freezing feature
> development on NVM for Windows.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue in a windows environment. I solved it by running the `nvm` commands in the command line `cmd` in the root directory `C:/` rather than the integrated terminal of `vscode`.

- Run cmd **as an administrator**
- **Download** the node version you want to use and **use** it

```
$ nvm download 12.18.0
$ nvm use 12.18.0
```

If you see the same error, you should configue the **PATH** in the **Environment Variables** like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112627/nvm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-windows) is saying.

- Go back to the other directory or in VsCode and try

```
node -v
```

and you'll see that you're using `12.18.0`

Answer (score 5):

Try to install the nvm directly in C:/ or in other folder without spaces in the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start powershell or Command Prompt as Administrator to use nvm-windows. See here https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score 1):

Spacing in the path is the problem.

You can run:

`nvm root` and find the root folder

then, copy the contents to another folder without any spaces on the path

After that move the nvm root to that folder by running the command below (with full path)

`nvm root [path]`

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, all you have to do is simply add the path of the bin of the node_modules to the environment variables.
The path will be: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
(Do not copy this path, this is an example. You can find the path of bin in your C drive)

Answer (score 0):

After running nvm install "version No" run CMD as administrater and then run nvm use "version No" and It will work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34435085)